# UnxUtils.zip: GNU utilities for Win32 (download link)

Tags: windows, unix, gnu

Where can I find the latest [Gnu utilities](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) for windows to download?

The [download link in the project homepage is a 403](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/UnxUtils.zip).

Comment: my personal preference is http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/

Click the green button. ;)

Note that most binaries are under /usr/local/wbin.

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/UnxUtilsSrc.zip/download

Forgotten, but certainly not dead! I use Ubuntu primarily. But do have the occasional need for Windows. And in the command shell I find myself instinctively using Unix commands (ls instead of **dir**, clear instead of **cls**). I know the old DOS commands, don't get me wrong. But now the newer Unix commands are instinctive. And when the XP command shell throws an error, it's irritating.

SourceForge does keep these useful files handy. But they tend to shift from time to time. The current link is valid.